# Unity and lifetime management

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I don't know how to describe this in a good way, but here goes.

I have 4 classes: A,B,C,D.

A is injected with B,C,D
C is injected with D

A is per resolve.
B is a singleton.
C and D I don't know.

I want A and C to use the same instance of D, so each time I resolve A from the container, D should be created once and injected into both A and C.

The easiest way would be to make A simply pass D to C without using Unity. But is there a way to do this with Unity? I've only been using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager and PerResolveLifetimeManager and never child container, which I suspect might be useful. I've being playing a bit with this, but it turns out quite messy. Can it be done easily?

Answer (score 11):

Is there a larger context in which you are operating? In ASP.NET I've created a PerRequestLifetimeManager that returns the same object when it is requested multiple times during a single HTTP request.

**EDIT:** Here's an implementation if you're interested.

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
    private readonly object key = new object();

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(key))
            return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(key);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = newValue;
    }
```

Comment: There is not an obvious one like a Http Session, but I guess I could make one. But what then? Which objects should I assign the PerRequestLifetimeManager to? If I only assign it to D, which seems to be the obvious, B wouldn't get a new since it's singleton. Should I then also change B? In a big application which many dependencies, it will get difficult to manually figure out which types should be of PerRequestLifetimeManager. Please tell a bit more about how it works, it seems like a good idea, but I don't understand it fully.

Comment: I was thinking that D would resolve one-per-request. Your scenario doesn't indicate that B holds a reference to D. If it does, then B will only ever have one instance of D making your scenario impossible to resolve (unless D is also a singleton). Your scenario may be too complex to resolve in the abstract. If you specified some basic function for A,B,C and D then maybe I could shed some better light.

Comment: Thanks, how do you decide which types/instances should use this lifetime manager? Do you use it for all registrations?

Comment: It really just depends on what kind of state the type has, what resources it uses, and what it depends on. You need to keep dependencies in mind when determining lifetimes, since if X is a singleton, then anything that X depends on will only created once for X as well.

Comment: >>since if X is a singleton, then anything that X depends on will only created once for X as well.     Yes, that's exactly my worry. It seems to me that I will manually have to figure out what the dependencies are. In a big application it will be error prone, and I think it would be possible for Unity to figure it out for me, at least theoretical :-)

Comment: Proposed implementation has the drawback of not handling releasing of dependencies at request end. For this, the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager` implementation is exactly what is needed provided its associated module `UnityPerRequestHttpModule` is registered. And its implementation currently does not even depend on MVC. Unfortunately, its assembly does, cause of some other classes it contains.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe I don't know why unity containers works in such a way that if a main object has ContainerControllerLifeTImeManager then it's dependent objects(injected) also gets the same life time though they are configured differently like TransientlifeTimeManager. This really confuses when using objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC3, you can take a look at Unity.Mvc3 http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com

Description on site says "A library that allows simple Integration of Microsoft's Unity IoC container with ASP.NET MVC 3. This project includes a bespoke DependencyResolver that creates a child container per HTTP request and disposes of all registered IDisposable instances at the end of the request."

Usage http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/integrating-the-unity.mvc3-1.1-nuget-package-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to share D between A & C when A is resolved. What about when something else is resolved?

If it's just "one instance of D everywhere" that's ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.

If you want to share D only in this particular instance, you can register D with a name and either PerResolve or ContainerControlled depending on the semantics you want. Then, when configuring A & C, inject D with that specific name.

If it's something else I'll need more details.

You probably won't need to go into child containers for this one.

Comment: It's a D each time A is resolved, so ContainerControlledLifetimeManager won't work neither would naming it

Answer (score 0):

Configure C's life time manager as PerResolve or ContainerControlled and keep D's life time as ContainerControlled